# Как проверить при вставке, что одно из двух полей должно быть NULL?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица об исторических деятелях, одна из колонок хранит дату рождения, так как mysql не поддерживает дату до н.э. пришлось ввести `int` полe для хранения года до н.э. Соответственно только одна из этих колонок может быть заполнена другая должна = `NULL`, как указать это ограничение явно, чтобы база данных заботилась об этом?

Вот два поля

```
birthday DATE DEFAULT NULL,
brithday_BC INT DEFAULT NULL
```

Только одно из этих полей имеет смысл. Как наложить на их ограничение которое мешало бы установить два поля сразу, то есть одно должно быть `NULL` по любому.

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятно сформулирован. Постарайтесь более четко и ясно выразить проблему и приложите к вопросу структуру вашей таблицы.

Comment: а если хранить во втором поле год, который потом вычитать из даты в первом поле?

Comment: а с датами будут производится какие-то действия? можно все, вообще, в одном поле типа varchar хранить

Comment: скорей всего будут.

Comment: Есть вариант, как уже продлагали, в одном поле хранить дату, а в другом коррекцию в годах (или тысячелетиях). Если же делать контроль целостности самой базой, то только триггером на insert и update.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения задачи можно воспользоваться before-триггером на операцию `INSERT`, который проверит, что одно или оба поля принимают значение `NULL`. Если условие не выполняется, отменить дальнейшее выполнение запроса можно путем генерации сигнала при помощи `SIGNAL SQLSTATE`. Можно воспользоваться сигналом 45000, предназначенным для пользовательских ошибок, не подлежащих перехвату.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER check_dates BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.birthday IS NOT NULL AND NEW.brithday_BC IS NOT NULL THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'One of birthday or brithday_BC must be NULL'; 
  END IF;
END//
```

Такой же триггер потребуется и на операцию `UPDATE`.